# PHP remove duplicate array values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-unique

Let me explain my situation,
i got myself a multidimensional array..
Down below is the `print_r` of my array.

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [firstname] => Tinga
            [lastname] => 
            [email] => private@information.nl
            [country_code] => NL
            [group] => B2B
            [order_count] => 321
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [firstname] => Tinga
            [lastname] => 
            [email] => private@information.nl
            [country_code] => NL
            [group] => B2B
            [order_count] => 12
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [firstname] => Rijsbergen Automotive B.V.
            [lastname] => 
            [email] => private@information1.nl
            [country_code] => NL
            [group] => B2B
            [order_count] => 311
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [firstname] => Mike Verhoef
            [lastname] => Artis Garage Amsterdam
            [email] => private@information2.nl
            [country_code] => NL
            [group] => B2B
            [order_count] => 260
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [firstname] => Marc Kraak
            [lastname] => Vakgarage TEMA
            [email] => private@information3.nl
            [country_code] => NL
            [group] => B2B
            [order_count] => 257
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [firstname] => J&B Auto's
            [lastname] => 
            [email] => private@information4.nl
            [country_code] => NL
            [group] => B2B
            [order_count] => 249
        )
)
```

As you can see, there is a duplicate array, only the `order_count` is different.

I can easily remove the duplicates using `array_unique`, but then it removes one of the arrays randomly(i believe).

What i want is to remove the duplicates based on email (private_information) with the least amount of `order_count`. (So only keep the one with the highest `order_count`)

Anyone who can help me out here?

Comment: Show sql query which gives you such results.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @u_mulder The results come from a json file. The duplicates are from customers who create more than 1 account on the webshop.

Comment: If you have access to creating this json file - fix it.

Comment: @u_mulder so far i tried building a function myself, was hoping maybe there was already a function i was not aware of that solves my problem. Figured it would save me some time.

Comment: @lzzy this might work for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php

Comment: @u_mulder i don't have acces to create the file. I need to use the json file and take the data from there.

Comment: @skndrkhtr5 it definitely removes the duplicates, but it can remove the wrong array. Im trying to remove the array with the highest order_count. This way the most active account wont get removed.

Comment: @lzzy you want to show arrays (max order counts + remove duplicates)?

Comment: @skndrkhtr5 yes sir!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution based on provided array is:

```
$filtered = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $email = $item['email'];

    if (empty($filtered[$email]) || $filtered[$email]['order_count'] < $item['order_count']) {
        $filtered[$email] = $item;
    }
}
```